# How to calculate the start time of a recognized text in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

In the event of `Recognizing` and `Recognized`, there is `Duration` and `OffsetInTicks`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognitionresult?view=azure-dotnet

It says that `Duration` does not include trailing or leading silence.

In order to make a subtitle for an audio, the time of silence is needed to position the text in the correct moment.

I thought `OffsetInTicks` might be counting the leading silence in ticks, since it is "**Offset** of the recognized speech in ticks." But surprisingly, my ticks are the same for all `Recognized` events!

What is the correct way to obtain the start moment of each recognized text?

Comment: did you find solution? Can you post your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API call will take the **POST** calls and make the model to understand the location of the input for recognition. Once the input is given, then the complete model will have the single **StartTime and UpdatedTime**. If we need to get the start time of tick of each text when recognized, we need to assign **one individual input file to individual model.**

Checkout the format of the output of **JSON file** and the **GET** requestion using **POST** method below.

**POST METHOD:**

```
curl -v -X GET "{POST response}" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {key}"
```

**Prebuild response:**

```
{
    "status": "succeeded",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-03-25T19:31:37Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-03-25T19:31:43Z",
    "analyzeResult": {
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-30",
        "modelId": "model_name",
        "stringIndexType": "textElements"...
    ..."pages": [
            {
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "angle": 0,
                "width": 8.5,
                "height": 11,
                "unit": "inch",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "content": "CONTOSO",
                        "boundingBox": [
                            0.5911,
                            All the values of bounding box of time taken to convert 

                        ],
                        "confidence": 1,
                        "span": {
                            "offset": 0,
                            "length": 7
                        }
                    },
}
```

For the reference checkout the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-rest-api)